# Numpy : How to assign directly a subarray from values when these values are step spaced

Tags: numpy, variable-assignment, numpy-ndarray, sub-array, numpy-slicing

I have 2 global arrays "`tab1`" and "`tab2`" with dimensions respectively equal to `21x21` and `17x17`.

I would like to assign the block of "`tab1`" ( indexed by `[15:20,0:7]`) by the block of "`tab2`" indexed by `[7:17:2,0:7]` (so with a step between elements of 1st array dimension) : I tried whith this syntax :

```
tab1[15:20,0:7] = tab2[7:17:2,0:7]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, it seems that only "diagonal" (I mean one by one) elements of `15:20` are taken into account following the values of "`tab2`" along `[7:17:2]`.

Is there a way to assign a subarray of "`tab1`" with another subarray "`tab2`" composed of indexes with step spaced values ?

If someone could see what's wrong or suggest another method, this would be nice.

**UPDATE 1:** indeed, from my last tests, it seems good but is it also the same for the  assignment of block `[15:20,15:20]` :

```
tab1[15:20,15:20] = tab2[7:17:2,7:17:2]
```

??

ANSWER : it seems ok also for this block assignment, sorry

Comment: Can't reproduce, just works for me. Suggest you provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment works as I expect.

```
In [1]: arr = np.ones((20,10),int)
```

The two blocks have the same shape:

```
In [2]: arr[15:20, 0:7].shape                                                                  
Out[2]: (5, 7)
In [3]: arr[7:17:2, 0:7].shape                                                                 
Out[3]: (5, 7)
```

and assigning something interesting, looks right:

```
In [4]: arr2 = np.arange(200).reshape(20,10)                                                   
In [5]: arr[15:20, 0:7] = arr2[7:17:2, 0:7]                                                    
In [6]: arr                                                                                    
Out[6]: 
array([[  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],        
        ...
       [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
       [ 70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,   1,   1,   1],
       [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,   1,   1,   1],
       [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,   1,   1,   1],
       [130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136,   1,   1,   1],
       [150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156,   1,   1,   1]])
```

I see a (5,7) block of values from `arr2`, skipping rows like [80, 100,...]